# Модуль для разработки на C++ для NetBeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

К нетбинс подключила модуль для разработки С/С++.

- Версия: 1.16.1.1.
- Источник: Дистрибутив NetBeans.
- Описание подключаемого модуля: Поддержка C/C++, включая редактирование, проекты, отладчик GDB и сборку. Предоставляется базовая поддержка Fortran и Assembler (x86/64, SPARC)

Создаю проект -- приложение на С/С++, в файле изначально присутствует такой код

```
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {    
    return 0;
}
```

Нетбинс подчеркивает `#include <cstdlib>` и на всплывающей подсказке пишет, что не удалось найти файл `include <cstdlib>`, аналогично - std - не удалось разрешить идентификатор std. Что-то нужно доустановить или что нужно сделать?
Или нужно создавать проект другого типа?
Подскажите, как начать работать?

Comment: А сам нетбинс говорит, что си++ работает? Нужно поставить MinGW.

Comment: MinGW под Linux - очень инетересно?
Мне лично неочевидно какая операционная система у автора вопроса.

Comment: ОС - ubunta 12.04

Comment: Попробуйте

    sudo apt-get install gcc
    sudo apt-get install g++

Comment: gcc у меня уже установлен, g++ установила, но нетбинс все так же подчеркивает include <cstdlib> и std и выдает те же всплывающие подсказки.
и при попытке откомпилировать проект нетбинс пишет, что компилятор с есть, а компилятора с++ нет.

Comment: попробуй инклуд заменить на stdlib.h
[cstdlib][1]


  [1]: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v9v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp9.aix.doc/standlib/header_cstdlib.htm

Comment: stdlib.h так же подчеркивает и пишет, что не может найти

Comment: вывод один - необходимо настроить path в NetBeans.

[Настройка среды IDE NetBeans для языков C/C++][1]


  [1]: http://netbeans.org/community/releases/69/cpp-setup-instructions_ru.html#compilers_linux

Comment: поставила sudo aptitude install build-essential,
перезагрузила компьютер, перезапустила нетбинс,
вроде все работает.
Еще такие вопросы:
1. когда создаю проект, нетбинс предлагает разные типы проекта: Проект С/С++ с существующими исходными файлами, Проект С/С++ на основе бинарного файла, Приложение на С/С++ и др.
Пока выбрала для своего проекта Приложение на С/С++, но может надо какой-то другой тип выбирать?
2.Не совсем понимаю, куда нетбинс кладет exe-файл
NetBeansProjects/c1/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/c1
тип: исполняемый (application/x-executable)
это он?
а как его запустить через терминал?